# In R which packages for loading larger data quickly

Tags: r

In R usually data is loaded in RAM.
Are there any packages which load the data in disk rather than RAM

Comment: In addition to Iterator's and Dirk's answer, for handling large data, there are sqldf, RMySQL, RSQLite (also noted in the HPC TV).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the `bigmemory` package, along with related packages like `bigtabulate`, `bigalgebra`, `biganalytics`, and more.  There's also `ff`, though I don't find it as user-friendly as the `bigmemory` suite.  The `bigmemory` suite was reportedly partially motivated by the difficulty of using `ff`.  I like it because it required very few changes to my code to be able to access a `bigmatrix` object: it can be manipulated in almost exactly the same ways as a standard matrix, so my code is very reusable.

There's also support for HDF5 via NetCDF4, in packages like `RNetCDF` and `ncdf`.  This is a popular, multi-platform, multi-language method for efficient storage and access of large data sets.

If you want basic memory mapping functionality, look at the `mmap` package.

Comment: Bigmemory started as just an external pointer to objects in ram outside of R, plus proper semantics. The file-based stuff came in response to ff, but that didn't start bigmemory.  You pointers to hdf5 and netcdf are good and correct too, as is the hint to mmap.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ff) package can do that.

You may want to look at the [Task View on High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for more details.